# "Active (Debug)" versus "Debug"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Visual Studio Debugger
**Project Settings for C# Debug Configurations**

- [Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05%28VS.90%29.aspx)
- [.NET 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05%28VS.71%29.aspx)

"Sets mode for compiling the application.
Choose among
**Active (Debug)**,  <========
**Debug**,           <========
Release,
All Configurations."

It appears that **Active (Debug)** and **Debug** are two separate choices.
However, the MSDN library fails to explain the difference between  **Active (Debug)** and **Debug**.

There's no information here:  "Visual Studio Debugger
Project Settings for C# Debug Configurations"

- [Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5%28VS.90%29.aspx)
- [.NET 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5%28VS.71%29.aspx)

I could not find any explanation via Google either.

QUESTION:
What is the difference between  **Active (Debug)** and **Debug**?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Active tab is to denote the currently active configuration.  In the case of Active (Debug) it is noting the active configuration is the debug one.

You can demonstrate this by changing the current configuration to Release and then revisiting the Debug tab.  It will now display Active (Release).

Comment: Thank you Jared; I just also found the explanation in a note here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166577.aspx:
"The configuration in parentheses vary depending on the currently selected active configuration." ~~ imho the way Microsoft described this in the pages that I've mentioned is confusing (at least to me).

Comment: So what are the other options (besides `Active`) in **Properties Build** for? (I tried putting conflicting entries (`x64 vs x86, Debug vs Release`) there and in **Configuration Manager**, and VS always followed Configuration Manager.)

Comment: This is a design issue then? If I understand correctly? A field that has a purpose only to be displayed for state information is presented as a selectable option in a drop-down-list here? This makes little sense to the user (the fact this question even exists supports that argument). I am viewing this in VS 2012, will this be changed? In my humble opinion it should be.

Answer (score 9):

Active refers to the currently active configuration, there is a drop down list in the standard toolbar that allows you to define the current active configuration, when you change these the "Active" configuration in project properties will change.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Richard for explaining the connection between the two drop down lists.  Microsoft should hire Jared and you to clean up their documentation.

Comment: on VS 2010 express, this toolsbar's item is only visible on "expert settings mode" : menu tools / settings / expert mode.