# what difference between active(debug) and debug in xcode configuration

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I want to know that what difference between active(debug) and debug with configuration when I show a build tab of project info, and can also tell me that what difference between project info and target info, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Active tab is to denote the currently active configuration. In the case of Active (Debug) it is noting the active configuration is the debug one.

You can demonstrate this by changing the current configuration to Release and then revisiting the Debug tab. It will now display Active (Release).

Target info lets you edit configurations about specific targets but the Project info lets you change setting about the whole project and apply no matter what target it is. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jennis Just take a look at that [indepth explanation Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3427853/1059705)